# A word meaning "Joy in being outraged"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for taking delight in being made angry?

It seems like in today's Twitterverse of "gotcha politics" this word should exist, my friend suggested coining the word "Shadenfervor" but it doesn't quite fit the task at hand.

Comment: The question "is there a word for being trolled" has the same answer.

Comment: ... ***outrageous***?

Comment: Does it have to be a single word?

Comment: @Mitch preferably.  I'm not sure a perfect word exists, but that is what I'm lookin' for

Answer (score 1):

The terms **anger-affinity** or **anger-empowerment** are terms that describe exactly that. Per *Merriam-Webster* ...

> **[affinity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinity) :**  a liking for or an attraction to something
>
> **[empowerment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empowered) :**  to give power to (someone)

Essentially...

- **anger-affinity** describes somebody who is attracted to anger
- **anger-empowerment** describes somebody who is empowered (gains power) from anger

Unrelated, but the above terms are also refer to *The Hulk/Bruce Banner*, as it is his [ability to gain more strength when he is angry.](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Anger_Empowerment) So basically, it isn't a serious term (it's a fun one movie reference), which is why I think it's well suited to Twitter and its *gotcha-politics.*

Answer (score 1):

This concept is gaining attention.

Here's a very good talk talk I suggest watching if you're interested. [How one tweet can ruin your life - Jon Ronson.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QtwIwAGoVChMIjrybqoC0yAIVgsamCh2RPwQv&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwAIP6fI0NAI&usg=AFQjCNEv867LMSZaFecp39R8UMjGD17tzw&sig2=HbK8XQDcdCwH1WJhOKvCfw)

The terms I'd suggest are:

- Outrage addiction ["Why we're addicted to online outrage."](http://theweek.com/articles/449473/why-addicted-online-outrage)
- Self-indulgence ["Cecil the lion, and America's animal loving self-indulgence."](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2015/08/02/1408168/-Cecil-the-Lion-and-America-s-Animal-Loving-Self-indulgence)
- Internet hate machine ["Rise of the internet hate machine"](http://op-talk.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/06/16/rise-of-the-internet-hate-machine/?_r=0)

I think **outrage indulegence** or **outrage addiction** best describes the concept - people getting enjoyment by being outraged and thus feeling morally superior to the target of outrage.

Comment: It's closer than the other answer, but it's not quite there.  Still, "outrage indulgence" is one I'll keep in mind.